# Compare cell to previous cell and if different paste data elsewhere, else increment

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a VBA macro for Excel that will go down one column and compare one cell to the previous cell to see if they are the same or not.  If they are the same I want it to do nothing and continue on down the column.  If they are not the same then I want to copy multiple columns in that row and paste them in a separate tab or spreadsheet.

Basically my data is a list of pressures taken every two seconds and I have thousands of data points.  I want to export only the pressure and elapsed time so that I have a much smaller set of data that is more useful.  Basically I want to clean up my data to only show changes in pressure and the times at which the pressures change.

I was able to figure out a macro that works.

```
Sub testIt()
Dim r As Long, endRow As Long, pasteRowIndex As Long

endRow = 3725 ' of course it's best to retrieve the last used row number via a function
pasteRowIndex = 1

For r = 1 To endRow 'Loop through sheet1 and search for your criteria

If Cells(r, Columns("C").Column).Value <> Cells(r + 1, Columns("C").Column).Value Then 'Found

        'Copy the current row
        Rows(r).Select
        Selection.Copy

        'Switch to the sheet where you want to paste it & paste
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        Rows(pasteRowIndex).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste

        'Next time you find a match, it will be pasted in a new row
        pasteRowIndex = pasteRowIndex + 1


       'Switch back to your table & continue to search for your criteria
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
End If
Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show what you have so far code-wise?

Comment: I have been trying different codes but here is an example that I am trying to work on. I also tried the answer below but had issues  
Sub data()
'
' data Macro
'
'
    
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Range("C8").Activate
    While ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0) <> ""
        If ActiveCell = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0) Then
        ActiveCell = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0)
        Else
        Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Copy
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        Range("B9.offset(i,0)").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        i = i + 1
        End If
    Wend
    
    
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.  Mark as answered if this helps!

```
Sub compare()(
  for I = 2 to Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count,"A").End(xlup).Row
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & I)<>Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & I-1) then
        'move data
         For j = 1 to rows
             For k = 1 to columns
                Sheets("Sheet2").cells(j,k)=Sheets("Sheet1").cells(j,k)
                Sheets("Sheet3").cells(j,k)=Sheets("Sheet1").cells(j,k)
              Next k
         Next j
     End if
  Next I
End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting a runtime error 13  type mismatched on the line for j = 1 to rows.  I am not very good with visual basic and I have been searching and trying to use other peoples examples but am having issues.  also I had to remove the open parenthesis after the sub compare().